# How do I add the "-Djdk.tls.maxCertificateChainLength=15" jvm option within a maven javafx project

Tags: java, maven, javafx, webview, jvm-arguments

I have a program that uses **JavaFX** WebView to open a webpage that sends too many chains. The Third-Party web page did not do this until a week ago.

Here is my pom file.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>opn.greenwebs</groupId>
<artifactId>WebViewExample</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>16</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>opn.greenwebs.webviewexample.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                    <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                    <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                    <id>debug</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <options>
                            <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                    <id>ide-debug</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <options>
                            <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                    <id>ide-profile</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <options>
                            <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                            <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                            <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                            <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                            <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>--module-path</argument>
                    <modulepath/>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath/>
                    <argument>opn.greenwebs.webviewexample.App</argument>  
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and my fxml controller.

```
package opn.greenwebs.webviewexample;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;


public class AppyController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    WebView webView;
    @FXML
    WebEngine webEngine;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.setOnError(event2 -> {
            System.out.println("hey what is the error " + event2.getMessage());
        });
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleClose(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("we are closing the door");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleLoadWeb(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            Worker<Void> worker = webEngine.getLoadWorker();
            worker.stateProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) -> {
                System.out.println("what is newValue " + newValue);
                if (newValue == Worker.State.FAILED) {
                    System.out.println("what is the message " + worker.getException());
                }
            });
            webEngine.load("https://ec.synnex.ca/ecx/");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("we have an exception " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and my fxml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="414.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="opn.greenwebs.webviewexample.AppyController">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="webView" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="358.0" prefWidth="572.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="42.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0" />
      <Button layoutX="534.0" layoutY="374.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleLoadWeb" text="Load Web Page" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" />
      <Button layoutX="433.0" layoutY="375.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleClose" text="Close" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="122.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I get this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: The certificate chain length (11) exceeds the maximum allowed length (10)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateMessage.<init>(CertificateMessage.java:874)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1169)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1498)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1404)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:441)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:412)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:574)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1653)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at opn.greenwebs/opn.greenwebs.Main1.lambda$start$2(Main1.java:88)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:181)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyStringPropertyBase.java:78)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyStringWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.updateLocation(WebEngine.java:434)
    at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1358)
    at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1240)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2524)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2369)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkOpen(Native Method)
    at javafx.web/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.open(WebPage.java:1246)
    at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.load(WebEngine.java:901)
    at opn.greenwebs/opn.greenwebs.Main1.start(Main1.java:113)
    at opn.greenwebs/opn.greenwebs.App.lambda$addAppToTray$4(App.java:261)
    at FXTrayIcon@3.0.0/com.dustinredmond.fxtrayicon.AWTUtils.lambda$null$0(AWTUtils.java:74)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:447)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

[@Dave_Thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085) suggests to add `-Djdk.tls.maxCertificateChainLength=15` to JVM options.

Where do I put the **JVM** option so my maven project will work again?

Comment: Hello, please format your code next time :) also, welcome to SO!

Comment: You have to add this option at runtime. If you are launching your project through Maven, then yes, you need to tweak Maven - please post how are you starting it and any relevant configuration. (Probably using the exec plugin - in which case the full doc is [here](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)) If you are not starting the app through Maven, post how exactly are you starting it. Note - even if you are starting the app through Maven for development, you may also need to think how is it going to start in production and make additional adjustments.

Comment: That is a really bizarre setup on the 3rd party site to have such a long cert chain.